# Crosstab for multiple variables like correlation plot

Tags: r, pivot-table

I'm quite a beginner in R and just don't know how to solve this following probem:
I have 12 binary variables/columns in my dataframe (1 = yes, 2 = no) showing whether a person studies this subject at university or not.
What I want is a table with 12 columns and the same 12 rows for each subject, counting only 1 = yes.  So the diagonal should be 100% or the exact number of persons who study each subject, and all the other cells should be a crossing of each 2. So I'm talking of a table that looks a bit like a correlation plot, but with frequencies.
I tried a lot with the function table(), but it does not work for more than 2 variables the way 1 want it. ftable() does not work eather.
Could you please help me?

So this would be an example of what my data looks like, except with just 5 subjects, instead of 12, and 10 cases instead of about 1000+.

```
set.seed(1234)

math <- sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
physics <- sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
it <- sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
biology <- sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
chemistry <- sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(math, physics, it, biology, chemistry))
```

So I need a crosstable with the columns 'maths', 'physics', 'it', 'biology', 'chemistry' and the exact same rows, showing frequencies.
In this example, the cell of 'math' and 'physics' contains a '2', because 2 people from my sample have a '1' in these columns, meaning they study both subjects (row 3 and 6)
'biology' and 'chemistry' would have '0', because no one in my sample of 10 studies both of these subject.

I really hope, it's clear now what I would need.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data that you have? It would be useful to provide a solution.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer to my previous question. Thank you for asking!